# Symmetry action on $k$-space creation operator

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory, second-quantization

Assuming I am working in a periodic system and performing a plane wave expansion, I generally have creation/annihilation operators given by $c_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{Q}}$. The action of a symmetry $g$ is given by

$$ 
gc_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{Q}}^\dagger g^{-1} = \sum_{\mathbf{Q}'}\left[D(g)\right]_{\mathbf{Q}',\mathbf{Q}}c^\dagger_{g\mathbf{k},\mathbf{Q}}
$$

where $g\mathbf{k}$ is the momentum after acting on momentum $\mathbf{k}$ with $g$. I've seen this written in various papers, but I'm confused by how one actually derives this expression? Why does the action of a symmetry operator take this form, and how would one find $D(g)$ for a known symmetry?

Answer (score 0):

The creation operators $c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}}$ create states which are vectors so you are asking how a symmetry group acts on a vector space. The most natural transformations on a vector space are the ones implemented by linear operators so it is almost always assumed that the action of a symmetry is a *linear action* also known as a *linear representation*. Once you know that the $c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}}$ transform in some $N$ dimensional linear representation, then by definition it is true that the group element $g$ acts as
\begin{equation}
c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}} \mapsto D(g) c^\dagger_{g\textbf{k}} \quad\quad (1)
\end{equation}
where $D(g)$ is an $N \times N$ matrix obeying
\begin{equation}
D(gh) = D(g)D(h). \quad\quad (2)
\end{equation}
The form of (1) you have written is the one that labels the $N$ components of $c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}}$ with another index $\textbf{Q}$. For this form not to hold, the symmetry would have to act nonlinearly. There are nonlinear [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) where the group law (2) holds for $D(g)$ that are nonlinear maps instead of matrices. But these actions playing a role in a physical system would probably suggest some mysterious underlying structure.

If all you know is the symmetry group $G$ then there are infinitely many possibilities for $D(g)$; one for each linear representation. If you know $G$ and $N$ this is usually also not enough to specify a unique representation. To know $D(g)$, you basically have to be told what it is for the particular system being studied. The main challenge here is that the most common way to specify it uses very compact notation. E.g. the paper will give a set of Dynkin labels for the representation. One then needs to parameterize group elements by some co-ordinates $x_a$ and write
\begin{equation}
D(g) = \exp \left ( i \sum_a x_a T_a \right )
\end{equation}
where the $T_a$ are generators of the associated Lie algebra which are built from the Dynkin labels in a [convenient basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley_basis).